# regex to match a series of file types in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess

this is going to be a silly question I guess but I don't see what is going on here. I want to match a certain set of URIs via a regex in an .htaccess file.

I want the following

- All files that don't contain a .
- all files ending on .htm / .html
- all files ending on .php

So:

```
^[^.]+$
```

works to match all files with no dot in the URI.

```
\.html?$
```

matches all .html / .htm files

```
(^[^.]+$)|(\.html?$)
```

seems to work combining both

```
(^[^.]+$)|(\.html?$)|(\.php$)
```

fails to combine things with the match files ending on php case. test.jpg for example matches now while it should not.

I must be missing something obvious. 
What is it? Thanks.

**Update:** here is the entire context I was using:

```
### REWRITE RULES ###
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (^[^.]+$)|(\.html?$)|(\.php$) bootstrap.php [L,QSA]
```

bootstrap.php contains:

```
echo "testing bootstrap";
```

Querying a non existing .jpg

```
http://localhost/test.jpg
```

gives me this output:

```
testing bootstrap
...
```

**Update 2:**

After testing the first answer below I found that using the simple:

```
RewriteRule \.php$ bootstrap.php [L,QSA]
```

fails in the same way as the above. It matches test.jpg. There is nothing crazy in the server configuration or .htaccess file though... This is all there is in the .htaccess file except what I posted already:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
AddType application/x-httpd-php .xml
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
```

**Answer:** (Couldn't anwer my own question for 8 more hours...)

Thanks everyone for helping me out.
Special thanks to @mario who helped me solve this by his comment below.
It was a silly question indeed. Here is what was happening:

rewrite.log:

```
strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web_Root/test.jpg -> test.jpg
applying pattern '\.php$' to uri 'test.jpg'
pass through D:/Web_Root/test.jpg
strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web_Root/errors/404.php -> errors/404.php
applying pattern '\.php$' to uri 'errors/404.php'
RewriteCond: input='D:/Web_Root/errors/404.php' pattern='!-d' => matched
rewrite 'errors/404.php' -> 'bootstrap.php'
...
```

So the problem was that my 404 document ended on *.php which was why *.jpg matched for the not found file. Ah Bats, I would have searched this one for a long time...

So this does it:

```
RewriteRule ([^4]?[^0]?[^4]\.php) bootstrap.php [L,QSA]
```

Well, the complete question's answer is:

```
RewriteRule (^[^.]+$)|(\.html?$)|([^4]?[^0]?[^4]\.php) bootstrap.php [L,QSA]
```

Again: Thanks people.

Comment: That could be written a little better, but test.jpg still wouldn't match from that...unless you had like "test.jpg.php" or something...what are you trying to use the pattern with? (p.s. - I didn't vote to close this topic..dunno who did but this question IS relevant to SO...)

Comment: I added the information on how I'm using it to the question. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Difficult to tell. You might want to try the `RewriteLog` to find out. (I believe mod_rewrite uses the standard posix regex functions, so it might not support ^ and $ within alternatives.)

Comment: @mario Thank you very much for that suggestion. I was unaware of this log option.

Comment: @mario I solved it due to your comment. See edit above. If you'd post the comment as an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: doh! /facepalm moments ftw :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Ok, this was not the specific solution here, but I'll make it a faux answer.]

When mod_rewrite rules go wrong, it sometimes helps to enable the [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog). It needs to be configured in the `httpd.conf` or `VirtualHost` section and thus is a bit effort. But there Apache will list the order and processing actions it performs and the URL. This can be helpful to see if the regex is understood by Apache and does behave as it should.

Note that it can sometimes remain empty - if the actual error source are `Alias` and `Redirect` rules or even `FileMatch` sections. In this case the `error.log` or even just the `access.log` might contain some hints however.

If all fails, you might have luck with temporarily enabling [`Nanoweb`](http://nanoweb.si.kz/) instead of Apache. It comes with a similar `mod_rewrite` implementation, which however uses PHPs [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) PCRE backend. (*Not telling why I know that.*)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
(^[^.]+$)|\.(html?$|php$)
```

*Edit:
I misunderstood what you were trying to do. What about this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^[^.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^.*\.(html?|php)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bootstrap.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No, it gives the same result. You have one '(' too few or one ')' too many above. But both ((^[^.]+$)|\.(html?$|php$)) and (^[^.]+$)|\.(html?$|php$) still match test.jpg in the scenario detailed above.

As soon as I remove the '|php' things work again. If I use the 'php' instead of the 'html?' that again does not work...

Comment: Thanks for replying, I solved it, see addition to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so it looks like your rewrite IS working...you can see your "testing bootstrap" message.  That "cannot modify header" warning is not related.  That means you are trying to do something like session_start() or header() or something after you already output something (probably that 'testing bootstrap' message)

Comment: Yes of course. But it should absolutely not work for the 'test.jpg' call. The warning is indeed unrelated. I took it out of the question. Thanks for pointing out that it was confusing.